# Deploy a symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, deployment, bundle

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony2 application in my production server and I got all the time this error:

```
[Wed Aug 21 13:34:09 2013] [error] [client 217.116.1.71] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FEB\\UserBundle\\FEBUserBundle' not found in /var/www/social-apps-nt.com/public_html/FEB/app/AppKernel.php on line 20
[Wed Aug 21 13:34:10 2013] [error] [client 217.116.1.71] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/social-apps-nt.com/public_html/FEB/src/FEB/UserBundle/FEBUserBundle.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/social-apps-nt.com/public_html/FEB/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 185
```

This is my appKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FEB\UserBundle\FEBUserBundle(),
            new FEB\TwitterBundle\FEBTwitterBundle(),
            new FEB\FacebookBundle\FEBFacebookBundle(),
            new FEB\CMSBundle\FEBCMSBundle(),
            new FEB\TagsBundle\FEBTagsBundle(),
            new FEB\YoutubeBundle\FEBYoutubeBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new Stfalcon\Bundle\TinymceBundle\StfalconTinymceBundle(),
            new FEB\DownloadableBundle\FEBDownloadableBundle(),
            new FEB\EmbeddableBundle\FEBEmbeddableBundle()
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

And the folders and classes is in the correct place and folder.

It seems like not find my custom bundles because If I change the lines always throws the error in line 20.

Any help, please???

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is "Permission denied" in the error message, it means that it couldn't open the file.

Check out if owner and chmod of the file is fine, chmod 755 sounds reasonable in most cases. 
You can change that by running `chmod 755 -R src` on Linux based systems, also make sure that your webserver user has access to the files .